# Android camera intent issues with some devices

Tags: android, android-intent

What I'm trying to do is take a photo using the camera intent, make a note of the URI (I will then use this later to upload the image via `Firebase` Storage), rotate the image if required, and then display the image in an `ImageView`. This is how I'm doing this at the moment, which works okay on an AVD and on a `Sony Xperia Z2` running `Marshmallow 6.0.1`. However, when tested on a `Samsung Galaxy S4` running `Lollipop 5.0.1`, I have issues. The code cannot find the image at the specified filepath. I have also tried setting the `ImageView` by using photoURI, and I have also tried commenting out the extras when creating the camera intent, and just getting the data via `data.getData()` - None of these methods are working. I just need a way to get this image from this device without it crashing and ideally without compromising on device compatibility.

> EDIT: Leading up to the camera intent taking over, both photoFilepath
>   and photoURI have values. As soon as I get to the `onActivityResult`,
>   both return null.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opt.inSampleSize = 8;
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){
            try {
                Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoFilepath, opt);
                Bitmap rotated = rotateImg(bit, photoFilepath);
                userPhoto.setImageBitmap(rotated);
                contentsOfImageView = rotated;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error retrieving photo, please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                contentsOfImageView = null;
            }
        } // else if here for handling getting images from gallery
        addBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        clearBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else { // Result was a failure
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Picture wasn't taken!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            Log.d(TAG, ex.toString());
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "com.example.intheactualcodethisismypackagename",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    photoFilepath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}

private Bitmap rotateImg(Bitmap before, String path) {
    ExifInterface exif = null;
    try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(path);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    switch (orientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            matrix.setRotate(90);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            matrix.setRotate(180);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            matrix.setRotate(270);
            break;
        default:
            break;

    }
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(before, 0, 0, before.getWidth(), before.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As soon as I get to the onActivityResult, both return null.

Most likely, your process was terminated while your app was in the background and the camera app was in the foreground. This is perfectly normal, though whether it happens on any given `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` request will vary.

Make sure that you hold onto relevant things, like your `Uri` and/or `File`, in the saved instance state `Bundle`, such as in [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/FileProvider):

```
/***
 Copyright (c) 2008-2016 CommonsWare, LLC
 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
 use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
 of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
 by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
 License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
 OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
 language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

 From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
 https://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.camcon;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

public class CameraContentDemoActivity extends Activity {
  private static final String EXTRA_FILENAME=
    "com.commonsware.android.camcon.EXTRA_FILENAME";
  private static final String FILENAME="CameraContentDemo.jpeg";
  private static final int CONTENT_REQUEST=1337;
  private static final String AUTHORITY=
    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".provider";
  private static final String PHOTOS="photos";
  private File output=null;
  private Uri outputUri=null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent i=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    if (savedInstanceState==null) {
      output=new File(new File(getFilesDir(), PHOTOS), FILENAME);

      if (output.exists()) {
        output.delete();
      }
      else {
        output.getParentFile().mkdirs();
      }
    }
    else {
      output=(File)savedInstanceState.getSerializable(EXTRA_FILENAME);
    }

    outputUri=FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, AUTHORITY, output);

    if (savedInstanceState==null) {
      i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputUri);

      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
      }
      else {
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList=
          getPackageManager()
            .queryIntentActivities(i, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
          String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
          grantUriPermission(packageName, outputUri,
            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION |
              Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        }
      }

      startActivityForResult(i, CONTENT_REQUEST);
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putSerializable(EXTRA_FILENAME, output);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                  Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CONTENT_REQUEST) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        i.setDataAndType(outputUri, "image/jpeg");
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
      }
    }
  }
}
```